# Embedding complete articles from another site on your own website. Legal?

Tags: legal, copyright, iframe, embed

Can you embed a complete article from another site on your own website? As is. Visitors will see that it's from another website but they don't have to leave your website to read the whole article.

This site goes into some depth about the issue but doesn't come to a concrete conclusion:
https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/website-permissions/linking/

Answer (score 3):

I long as you clearly mention the author or the article and the source, I don't see why it's illegal (unless the source has clearly stated so). But embed or iframes usually provides a bad user experience, especially on small screen and mobile devices.

Comment: 1+ for the bad user experience comment.  Do you have a suggestion for a mobile fallback?